# Count Distinct multiple columns

Tags: oracle, duplicates, distinct

I have records that get entered in on a month by month basis... Here is what a current query looks like pulling the results for the entire year. Please note that this is an Oracle Database.

My Query:

```
SELECT UMEMBERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE, PUBLICATIONDT
  FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE INDENTIFIER IN ('GROUP1') 
  AND PUBLICATIONDT >= DATE'2014-01-01'
  AND PUBLICATIONDT <= DATE'2014-12-31'
```

Actual Returned Results:

```
 UMEMBERID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | BIRTHDATE | PUBLICATIONDT
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1         | John      | Smith    | 6/26/1983 | 11/20/2014
 2         | Jane      | Smith    | 2/2/1980  | 11/21/2014
 3         |  Roger    | Rabbit   | 8/3/1982  | 11/20/2014
 4         |  Bugs     | Bunny    | 6/20/1983 | 11/19/2014
 5         |  Daffy    | Duck     | 4/3/1982  | 11/17/2014
 6         |  Winnie   | Pooh     | 2/27/1989 | 12/15/2014
 7         |  Jane     | Doe      | 8/5/1959  | 12/11/2014
 5         |  Daffy    | Duck     | 4/3/1982  | 12/9/2014
 3         |  Roger    | Rabbit   | 8/3/1982  | 12/9/2014
 10        |  John     | Doe      | 8/9/1992  | 12/18/2014
```

My Expected results would be the following:

```
 UMEMBERID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | BIRTHDATE | PUBLICATIONDT
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1         | John      | Smith    | 6/26/1983 | 11/20/2014
 2         | Jane      | Smith    | 2/2/1980  | 11/21/2014
 3         | Roger     | Rabbit   | 8/3/1982  | 12/09/2014
 4         | Bugs      | Bunny    | 6/20/1983 | 11/19/2014
 5         | Daffy     | Duck     | 4/3/1982  | 12/09/2014
 6         | Winnie    | Pooh     | 2/27/1989 | 12/15/2014
 7         | Jane      | Doe      | 8/5/1959  | 12/11/2014
 10        | John      | Doe      | 8/9/1992  | 12/18/2014
```

If you will notice in the actual returned results it is picking up an extra record for each Roger Rabbit (`11/20/2014` and `12/09/2014`) and Daffy Duck (`11/17/2014` and `12/09/2014`). In my expected results I only want to pick up the `12/09/2015` dates and display 8 records.

Comment: So you want the latest (max) `publicationdt` for each combination of the other four columns? Have you tried with max and group-by? (Seems like you have denormalised data in this table though, if the other columns - apart from a key - have duplicate values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT UMEMBERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE, MAX(PUBLICATIONDT)
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE INDENTIFIER IN ('GROUP1') 
AND PUBLICATIONDT >= DATE'2014-01-01'
AND PUBLICATIONDT <= DATE'2014-12-31'
GROUP BY UMEMBERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDATE;
```

Comment: This works perfectly in SQLDBX... now I just need to convert it to Tableau